# How to set columns to rows for time series plotting in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I'm starting with Pandas and this is driving me crazy and not sure how to apply "melt" or "pivot" on this. Any help is really appreciated in advance.

MY CURRENT DATA FRAME:

[image]

I want to manipulate the data frame for time series plotting to look like this:

TARGET DATA FRAME:

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html#pandas-dataframe-transpose)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Sales': ['Cars', 'Motos', 'Boats'],
    'Q1': [11000, 2000, 113000],
    'Q2': [14000, 4500, 115000],
    'Q3': [12100, 3100, 114100],
    'Q4': [11500, 1600, 111700]
})

print(df)

print(df.set_index('Sales').T)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin. The problem I have when I  transpose the matrix is that the original index gets transposed too and appears at the top of the columns as the first row, and then, it doesn't allow me to select any column. For instance, dfT['0'

Comment: For instance, dfT['0'] would crash as it is not identified as a 'Key'. Also, with the new transposed dataframe, I loose the original index in the firts column. After many attempts, I started to look at 'melt' and 'pivot' choices, but I'm getting a bit crazy :-(.

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin, this is what I needed :-)